# PostgreSQL function can't find object that exist - relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created a function that select * from a specific table which includes alter commands on specific constraints I have in my schema. My code looks like that:

```
v_sql='select * from my_table_alters'
for rec in exec v_sql
loop
raise notice '%',rec
execute rec;
end loop
```

However, when I run my func from psql:

```
mydb=>select my_function(my_parameter);
```

I'm getting the next error:

```
NOTICE:  alter table  nap_ip_discount drop constraint sys_c008736(I print 
that notice its not an error - that what Im trying to execute in my loop..)
constraint "sys_c008736" of relation "nap_ip_discount" does not exist
```

But when I check if that constraint exist :

```
mydb=>\d  nap_ip_discount drop constraint
```

I see :

```
"sys_c008736" CHECK (nap_discount_seq IS NOT NULL)
```

The table nap_discount_seq is under schema gaps but I am the owner of that schema and it is also in my search_path.

Comment: so when you run exact generated statement between `begin; rollback;` it executes OK?..

Comment: yes! , the output of my function :    
NOTICE:     PROCEDURE change_constraints : V_Step = 2.2 // SQLERRM = constraint "sys_c008736" of relation "nap_ip_discount" does not exist. but when I preform them in begin;rollback they work